# Get PowerEdge Raid Controller Virtual Disk name in Power Shell

Tags: powershell

I need to determine a drives number as assigned by windows in power shell based on the name of the virtual drive given to it by the Power Edge Raid Controller. In iDrac I can see the virtual drive name, but in the windows GUI or any power shell commands I have tried will not display this name. I do not have control over system setup, all that will be known ahead of time is the virtual disk names. Does anyone know how to access the virtual disk name? I'm stumped!

Long story short, I need to be able to determine which drive number correlates to which virtual name and then assign a partition path to that drive.

I have tried get-wmiobject win32_physicalmedia, win32_volume,win32_diskdrivetodiskpartition.

The problem seems to be that windows does not know about the name given to the drive in iDrac. I am at a loss as to how to reference that name from windows without using dell open manage or some other tool.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please show what you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

This is not really a solution but an idea on how this could work. Didn't test too much but eventually it will help you.

Most if not all raid controllers will not passthrough the VD name to the OS. So you will need to read the name and some additional information directly from the controller, for a Dell PERC you could use perccli. Following example will get you all virtual Disks from all controllers in json format:

```
percli /call /vall show j
```

From this you get a few information like Name, Size and the DG/VD ID. From what I see on my test system this ID seems to correlate with the SCSITargetId from Win32_DiskDrive:

```
Get-WmiObject Win32_DiskDrive | Where-Object {$_.InterfaceType -eq 'SCSI'} | Select-Object Size, SCSIBus, SCSITargetID
```

If you have more SCSI Controllers (e. g. an additional SCSI Controller for tapes) you will need to identify to which SCSIBus your PERC with the VD translates to.

Comment: Interesting! Thank you! Can the perc commands be used within powershell without installing any software or does one have to install perc cli tools?

Comment: You only need the perccli.exe, it can be run without being installed.